# call json location ajax google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

i have json data loction like this `{"name":"Tiesna","latitude":"123456","longitude":"9876543","posisi":"cirebon","waktu":"2015-07-01 21:49:52"}{"name":"Jastin","latitude":"-1234567","longitude":"987654","posisi":"susukan","waktu":"2015-07-01 23:11:52"}`

i want to call to google maps for location

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 50,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-39.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;
var markers = new Array();

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], 
                                     locations[i][2]),
    map: map
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking...

Comment: so what should I do ?

Comment: be more clear about what it is you want to know (are you trying to convert your json data to look like your locations array?  are you having trouble converting between projections? where exactly are you struggling?)

Comment: yes , I want to take the location data from json to google maps. I want to replace the loction var locations ... to json Data

Comment: can you provide a more accurate example of the json data?

Comment: {"name":"Tiesna","latitude":"33.890542","longitude":"151.274856"}

Answer (score 0):

I'm still having a little trouble understanding exactly what you are asking, but hopefully this will help...

If you have a JS object like the following

```
var loc1 = {"name":"Tiesna","latitude":"33.890542","longitude":"151.274856"};
```

you can push the relevant properties to your array with something like the following:

```
var locations = [];
locations.push([loc1.name, loc1.latitude, loc1.longitude]);
```

Comment: I have the data of this json `[ " Tiesna " , " 33.890542 " , " 151.274856 " , " Cirebon " , " 2015-07-02 11:32:23 " ]` as where to call using ajax to var locations